# Is there a way to use the Google Places API and the Geocoding API for free while developing?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps

I am developing a React Native app for the first time and I can see myself doing a lot of calls to test results, but I do not want to exceed my limit and get charged before releasing the app.

I know that the Maps API has the developer mode, but I did not see anything regarding this for the Places + Geocoding API.

Anyone has any experience in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Maps Platform offers a $200 monthly credit for Maps, Routes, and Places. With the $200 monthly credit, some customers find their use cases are at no charge. You won't be charged until your usage exceeds $200 in a month.

Note that the Maps Embed API, Maps SDK for Android, and Maps SDK for iOS currently have no usage limits and are at no charge (usage of the API or SDKs is not applied against your $200 monthly credit).

https://developers.google.com/maps/billing-credits